# How to add/wrap lines of text to .tex with .sh script

Tags: r, shell, scripting, insert, latex

I'm compiling a pdf with latex and have constantly ran into this issue: whenever I create a landscaped table I have to manually go within the .tex document and wrap

```latex
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
```

with

```latex
\scalebox{0.60}{
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}}
```

in order to ensure there's no truncation of the table when it's compiled to a pdf.

I primarily work through an R environment and create my .tex tables with the use of the `latex()` function from the `Hmisc` package; I haven't been able to find anything that helps with resizing a table via an argument via the `latex()` function.

So, I'm opting on creating a script that would wrap the tabular environment (i.e. wrap it with `\scalebox{}{}`) by first taking in the scale resizing parameter and then the .tex files that need to be resized:

```latex
~/scripts/scalebox_table.sh 0.60 table1.tex table2.tex table3.tex
```

If anyone has written a script that wraps certain texts with other texts, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sed -e 's/\(\\begin{tabular}\)/\\scalebox{0.60}{\n\1/g' -e 's/\(\end{tabular}\)/\1}/g' table*.tex`

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to parameterize a script to avoid hard-coding 0.60, and apply to all files. Change it to `sed -i -e ...` to edit the files in-place once you're comfortable that it works reliably.

Comment: Please move the answer into an actual answer.

Comment: Please, please, please don't use `\scalebox` for things that contain text, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for details. Better use a smaller font size or choose a different layout for the table. Can you show the code for the table? I'm sure there is a better way to fit it within the page

Comment: @r2evans thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@r2evans, with your help I was able to create this simple script.

```latex
SCALE=${1}
TEXFILE=${2}

sed -i -e 's/\(\\begin{tabular}\)/\\scalebox{'"${SCALE}"'}{\n\1/g' -e 's/\(\end{tabular}\)/\1}/g' ${TEXFILE}

exit 0
```